# Non-isomorphic algebras becoming isomorphic after adding identities: mistake in an exercise

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

In the book:  Drozd, Y.A., Kirichenko, V.V.: *Finite dimensional algebras*. Springer, Berlin (1994), there is an exercise which suggests a positive answer to the next question, and Ryszard R. Andruszkiewicz gives a counterexample:

Let $A,B$ be two arbitrary finite-dimensional algebras (spaces with associative laws) over a field $K$, and let $\overset{\sim}{A}:=\{(a,\alpha)\mid a\in A, \alpha\in K\}$, it is a well-known method of adjoining an identity to an arbitrary algebra $A$.

$$(a_1, α_1) · (a_2, α_2) = (a_1 · a_2 + α_2a_1 + α_1a_2, α_1α_2)$$
$$(a_1, α_1) + (a_2, α_2) = (a_1 + a_2, α_1 + α_2)$$
$$\forall\beta\in K:\beta· (a, α) = (βa, βα)$$

$\overset{\sim}{A}$ is an algebra with identity $(0, 1)$, in the same way we will define $\overset{\sim}{B}$.

The exercise: $A\cong B$ if and only if $\overset{\sim}{A}\cong\overset{\sim}{B}$.

Ryszard R. Andruszkiewicz's counterexample: [Surprise at adjoining an identity to an algebra](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10013-020-00437-9).

Andruszkiewicz's counterexample is, and if I understand correctly, $A$ is not isomorphic to $B$ because an isomorphism of algebras preserves both
the left and right identities, but $A$ has neither a right identity nor an identity while $B$ has a right identity.

Which shows that there might be an error in the exercise.

> Is it true that there is an error in the exercise?

Edit: For the discussion in the comments
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The counterexample is correct.  I had put the same counterexample on mathoverflow in a comment last year, unaware of the above paper, on a question asking about rings not isomorphic to their opposite.  See my comment on Pete Clark's answer to [Simplest examples of rings that are not isomorphic to their opposites](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64370/simplest-examples-of-rings-that-are-not-isomorphic-to-their-opposites).  Conceptually it is this. If you take a 2 element left zero semigroup $S=\{x,y\}$ with multiplication $ab=a$ for all $a,b\in S$ then obviously $x,y$ are distinct right identities and if $T$ is the opposite semigroup consisting of two right zeroes then $T$ has two distinct left identies.  Thus  the semigroup algebras $KS$ and $KT$ are not isomorphic over any field.  But when you adjoin identities to $KS$ and $KT$ (or equivalently adjoin an identity to the semigroups and take monoid algebras) you get algebras both isomorphic to $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrices.  The trick is in $KS^1$ where $S^1$ is the monoid obtained by adjoining an identity to $S$ the elements $1,1-x,1-y$ is a basis but $1-x,1-y$ form a right zero semigroup isomorphic to $T$.  So $KS^1\cong KT^1$.

Both the algebras live in $2\times2$ upper triangular matrices, which is the result of adding and identity. $KS$ consists of those upper triangular matrices whose second row is zero and $KT$ consists of those whose first column is zero.

I don't have the book.  By any chance were they assuming $A$ and $B$ have identities in the exercise?

Comment: @BenjaminSteiberg Thanks for your answer, I'm adding the original question to my post to clarify the question

Comment: Then the exercise is clearly mistaken.